# integrate values from a list into diccionary

Tags: python, list

I'm looking to do something similar to this: for each url item except item 0:

```
url = ['a.com', 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
for item in url[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7]:
    data ={
        "adSize": {"id":'{}'.format(item) }
        }
```

but in this way I have an error: `TypeError: list indices must be integers, not tuple`

Comment: Show us what you've tried

Comment: Show the desired result, the code you've written, and the problem you get from that code.

Comment: the code is so long. I said before that I tried with `'{}'.format(url[1]), '{}'.format(url[2]), '{}'.format(url[3]), '{}'.format(url[4]), '{}'.format(url[5]), '{}'.format(url[6]), '{}'.format(url[7])` in seven diferentes `data` but the script is so long in this way @donkopotamus

Comment: I just edited @Prune

Comment: Why do you need seven dictionaries with independent names?  A list of dictionaries would make this trivial.

Comment: I edited again. please check it @Prune

Comment: I edited again. please check it @donkopotamus

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your `for` syntax.  What do you mean by `url[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7]`?  You've given a sequence of seven values as if they're a subscript.  Perhaps you mean simply

```
for item in url:
```

This will walk `item` through each of the values in `url`, in turn.